# Start Page as default aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I hosted a website using VS2012. My problem is the Home page is not specified by default whenever I access the website. Pleases would you mind to show me how to add Default.aspx or Home.aspx into my Web.config so as I can edit it.

```
 <configuration>
     <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
         <assemblies>
           <add assembly=""/>
            <add assembly=""/>
           <add assembly=" "/>
         </assemblies>
     </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can right click the .aspx file you want to be default in visual studio, and then "Set as Start Page".

Comment: this only sets the start page within Visual Studio.

Comment: @ps2goat Yes, you are correct. However, that's exactly what was asked if you read the question.

Comment: ah, my mistake.  the web.config threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

In VS, you configure that by right clicking the web project, clicking Properties, going to the Web tab, and specifying a Specific Page for Start Action.

Note that this setting doesn't get set in `Web.Config`, and doesn't carry over when you deploy to IIS. You'd handle the default page within IIS Manager by setting the Default Document for your site.

Comment: My question is how to make Home.aspx as the default page in the File manager of my hosting portal!?

Comment: @Chris No, that's not your question. You specifically said you're hosting it in VS2012. And all the answers are based on that. So to change your question now would be in bad taste. You should create a new question and in the new question, specifically describe what you want. It might help to say something like "I'm hosting my site with <GoDaddy, Arvixe, Azure, or some other hosting service> and want to set the page that gets served when a user requests the root URL. How do I do that?" Make sure you check to see there's not a question that answers that first.

Comment: @Chris If you did, I would revert it. You already got 3 answers based on your current question. Changing it now would invalidate the answers, which is not polite. Instead, create a new question as I described above.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and I have three more days to fire up a question. Could you please suggest where do I look at in relation to query if you have any clue, please?

Comment: @Chris What hosting service are you using?

Comment: @chris Do you have another default.html or index.something file in there? IIS has several of these predefined, and the server admin determines the order in which they're used. If you have two in that directory **with different extensions**, the first in the list will be served...

Comment: @Chris I can't seem to access their support documentation. However, you should log in and see if they have documentation, or log into your website's host control panel and look for appropriate settings there.

Comment: Tim I have only  home.aspx page !

Comment: Will Do Mason, Thank you for your help

Comment: @Chris Tim was pointing out that web servers such as IIS often have default documents already specified. Even though you're not using IIS (at least not directly), you likely have a default document configured. You just need to log into your web hosting control panel and look for the appropriate settings.

Comment: Do you have access to host settings control? You need to change the Default document there.

Comment: I have access to the host portal but I can't find anything linked to set default as Home page?! However I email customer service and I've been asked to specify the Home page from web.config?!

Comment: @Chris, good plan. You're unlikely to get specific help about their particular hosting service here. But take a look at Ricardo's answer.

Comment: @mason He'll be notified anyway, it's his own question. I need to use @ even when obvious? (I'm not trying to be rude, just a real doubt).

Answer (score 0):

Well, just go to webconfig and add it:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
          <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="Path of your Page" />
          </files>
        </defaultDocument>  
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do I need to remove the assemblies !?

Comment: @Chris No, assembly configuration isn't related to defaultDocument.

Comment: So where to add these tags in my web.config?

Comment: @Chris I've updated his answer to reflect that `<system.webServer>` should be a child of the root `<configuration>` node.